# How to display images from my own server

Tags: html, image, path

Currently I'm using a path like "http://[My IP]/images/example.png" to access an image off my server while I see other codes use paths like "images/example.png" so I was wondering if I was doing this right for images hosted on my server.

If you can go off paths like "images/example.png" is it any different than using the paths I am now other than being shorter? Would it retrieve the image faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is an absolute URL. You can omit the domain name and just do:

```
/images/example.png
```

And it will function the same as your full URL (assuming the images are on the same domain as your website). Note that this is *not* the same as:

```
images/example.png
```

That is a *relative* URL. It is (unsurprisingly) relative to your current URL.

Comment: Ah, I just actually tried it on one of my webpages and it works just fine. I tried it earlier and it didn't work so I must've messed up the location or something. Sorry for wasting your time with this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the search always starts in current folder , so the path '/images/image' should be faster as well while being shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is basically the same. It's better to use paths like `/images/example` as you may want to change your domain name. You'd have to change each and every link and that'd be painful. They're also shorter and it means few bytes less sent by the server. This doesn't matter for small apps, but if you're handling a lot of requests, it may slow down your server a bit.